# Reliability of Docker containers

Tags: postgresql, docker

My question aims at verifying and maybe rectifying my idea of the reliability of Docker containers. I read both, the Docker documentation and several articles on `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile and `--v` as an argument when running a container as means to persist data outside a Docker container. Be it in a data container or on the host system. As would like to keep the complexity of my setup simple, I would prefer not to copy/save/store data round and about but keep it in the Docker container itself.

There are several cases through which I discovered the behaviour of Docker containers. I'd like to know if I missed a scenario where a container can be 100% lost unpurposely, i.e. NOT doing `$ docker rm -f mycontainer`

1. docker commands to pause, stop and kill a container
   -> restartable by `$ docker restart mycontainer` or `$ docker run mycontainer`
2. Host system reboot
   -> docker container exits with 0 or 255
3. Host system unexpected power off
   -> What happens?
4. Application exception
   -> docker container exits with -1
5. Updating or restarting docker (as pointed out by Greg)
   -> expected behavior: like on system reboot (?)

In all those cases, the docker container is still existent in the end. So is there any other scenario that can cause a docker container to be lost like with `$ docker rm -f mycontainer`?

The background is, that I read a lot about mounted volumes and external datastorage on the host system for Postgres but I'd like to avoid storing data outside my containers on the host system if possible. On the other hand, I don't want to wake up and have all data lost. (I do perform regular SQL-dumps, but I don't want to do this every 5 minutes). If a docker container itself is not reliable for persistant data, I don't see why I should create a second container to hold the data for a first one and increase the complexity of my system by adding a new container but not gaining anything in terms of reliability.

**Edit:** There are two points in the Docker [userguide on Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes) which do not explicitly explain which behaviour to expect and therefore making me question if these concepts provide extra reliability:

1. **Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an
   image**
   -> *Does that mean that they get lost or that the content of the volume won't be changed?*
2. **Volumes persist until no containers use them**
   -> *What's the definition of 'use'? As long as a container is not stopped, killed, removed? Does that mean that the volume Docker created on the host system will get removed? Or does volume only refer to a virtual bridge between a directory inside Docker and one on the host system?*

Comment: i am also struggling with the same question for postgres/docker. one thing that might be missing from your list is updating or restarting docker itself? also, by convention, you might want to treat all docker containers as stateless from an operations point of view: only consider 'data' containers when recovering.

Comment: That's a good point, Greg. I expect Docker to try to stop the containers gracefully like on system restart. It would be great to find a source in order to confirm this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you store all your data in the container, what are you going to do when you need to update the image? Updates to images are normally done by changing the Dockerfile and rebuilding the image. If my data is kept separate to my container, I can start a new version of the image, mount the data with `--volumes-from` or `-v` and kill the old container. In your case, you have to keep the container running and try to patch in place with something like puppet.

Also, I'm not sure what you think you're saving. If you run the official postgres image, it will have declared volumes in the Dockerfile. Those volumes exist as normal directories on your host system whether you ran the container with `-v` or not. Even if your Dockerfile has no volumes, clearly the UFS is being stored on your host anyway.

In general, you should consider containers to be temporary and stateless. Whilst you don't have to do this, you will find most of the tooling and support services are designed around this idiom.

Regarding your scenarios, there are a few you're missing:

- A bug could make it impossible to restart a stopped container
- The updating issue mentioned above
- If you want to change storage driver. This will cause a great deal of problems, as you need to migrate your images.

Just for clarity on the commands, `docker start` will restart stopped or exited containers and `docker unpause` will unpause paused containers.

Comment: I read through all this in the reference already and will answer to your post and clarify my concerns later again.